# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1502 into shape (48,48)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing, reshape

I have been stuck with this problem for a very long time and I could not find the solution.

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1502 into shape (48,48)
```

```py
#converting dtype of pixels to string
df['pixels'] = df['pixels'].astype("string")

pixels = df['pixels'].tolist() #Making list of pixels

width, height = 48, 48 # initializing image shape

# Converting to array and dimension for transfer Learning
faces = []
faces = np.asarray(faces)
faces = np.expand_dims(faces, -1)
faces /= 127.5 # normalizing the data
faces -= 1.

# Converting Emotions to NumPy array
emotions = pd.get_dummies(df['emotion']).to_numpy()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You would need 2304 elements to make an array of (48,48), but you only have 1502. How were you hoping to arrange 1502 elements into 2304 slots?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code. the code in your question contains no reshaping, so it can't have caused the exception, and it's nonsense anyway (`faces` is an empty list). your screenshot will receive no attention because you should have copied that text from the screenshot into your question. -- please take the [tour] and review [ask]  and [mre].

Comment: also,  is there an example of the `df`,  presumably `pd` comes from `import pandas as pd`...  hard to reproduce the code.

Answer (score 1):

`face` has 1502 elements. and what you are doing is, you want to change `face` shape to 48x48 since 48x48=2304. you need the same total value from before to after